# R: Export CSV with dates from getSymbols(), "quantmod" package

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I feel that I am possibly not understanding a table type. I'm pulling data using the package "quantmod" and function `getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo")`. The data shows up in my grid and is usable within R.

I'm trying to export via `write.csv()`, but the dates are turned into ascending numbers (1,2,3,...). Is there a way to export the date as well when it is a record name?

This is what I'm using:

```
write.csv(AAPL, "C:/Users/Desktop/AAPL.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

R shows:

Date - Price

CSV in excel shows:

1 - Price

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you import the data for AAPL it has dates in rownames thats why when you try to export it, it doesnt include the date.
USE THIS

```
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo")
```

After importing use the code below and then export x:

```
x<-data.frame(AAPL)
x$date<-rownames(x)
rownames(x)<-NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! I was under the assumption that row names were also record names and would be exported like SQL. I didn't realize that R stores a rownames() outside of the table and have to be added.

Comment: I was going down the route of dplyr() using: 
> AAPL$names <- rownames(AAPL)
It executes, but doesn't add a column? Any explanation on that?

Comment: So when you use getsymbols() it imports the data as "xts" in R.
You can read about xts here :[link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/vignettes/xts.pdf)      .. so you will have to change it to data.frame first to make any changes even if you want to use dplyr..

try to run **rownames(AAPL)** you will understand what i mean, the output of that is NULL

Comment: Thanks! Great information. I'm not 100% there with understanding xts, but this paper gives me the background information in understanding the why behind it. This seems very useful when I get into creating user defined functions. Another useful code line I experimented with is the as.data.frame() with an index(). Seems to work as well:  new_AAPL <- data.frame(index(AAPL), as.data.frame(AAPL)). Thank you again!

Comment: After diving into xts, there are a few quick useful time series functions, such as to.period(). Thank again for the read!

Answer (score 0):

`quantmod::getSymbols()` returns an xts object by default.  xts objects are based on zoo objects, which are a matrix with an 'index' attribute.  The date you see when xts/zoo objects are printed is the index attribute, not row names (or record names).

The easiest way to write xts/zoo objects to a text file is with `write.zoo()`. It will automatically include the index in the first column of the file.

```
write.zoo(AAPL, "aapl.csv", sep = ",")
readLines("aapl.csv", n = 5)
[1] "\"Index\",\"AAPL.Open\",\"AAPL.High\",\"AAPL.Low\",\"AAPL.Close\",\"AAPL.Volume\",\"AAPL.Adjusted\""
[2] "2007-01-03,12.327143,12.368571,11.7,11.971429,309579900,8.073009"                                   
[3] "2007-01-04,12.007143,12.278571,11.974286,12.237143,211815100,8.252192"                              
[4] "2007-01-05,12.252857,12.314285,12.057143,12.15,208685400,8.193427"                                  
[5] "2007-01-08,12.28,12.361428,12.182858,12.21,199276700,8.233888"
```

Comment: This worked great for exporting this xts to text. Thanks!